# IsUpdate Condition

Tags: apex, trigger

I have the following Apex trigger that is updating the Rep Look-up on my `Split` object.  The reason I did it this way and not a Workflow is because it had to be an editable field.  Recently they gave me a requirement for whenever `Rep_1_Production_Site_Rep_v3__c` gets updated, the `Customer_Number_from_ZipKey__c` needs to also be updated.  So I thought to use `.IsUpdate`, am I thinking of it wrong?

```
trigger UpdateRep1onSplits on Split__c(before insert, before update) {
Set < id > addSet = new Set < id > ();
for (Split__c s: Trigger.new) {
    if (s.Rep_1_Production_Site_Rep_v3__c == null) {
        addSet.add(s.Production_Site_Address__c);
    }
}

Map < id, Address__c > addMap = new Map < id, Address__c > ([SELECT Name, Rep_Account_Lookup__c, Zip_Key__c, ZipKey_Alias__c, Customer_Number_from_ZipKey__c FROM Address__c WHERE id IN: addSet]);
system.debug('addMap' + addMap);
for (Split__c cs: Trigger.new) {
    if (addMap.containsKey(cs.Production_Site_Address__c)) {
        cs.Rep_1_Production_Site_Rep_v3__c = addMap.get(cs.Production_Site_Address__c).Rep_Account_Lookup__c;
        // cs.Rep_1_Customer_Number_v2__c = addMap.get(cs.Production_Site_Address__c).Customer_Number_from_ZipKey__c;                                  
        if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
            cs.Rep_1_Customer_Number_v2__c = addMap.get(cs.Production_Site_Address__c).Customer_Number_from_ZipKey__c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you have multiple conditions such as `before insert, before update`, occasionally you need to run different logic depending on which case the trigger is handling and that is when `Trigger.isUpdate` etc. are useful. They are essentially object level rather than field level indicators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically this is done by comparing the field's former value with the current value, such as in the example below:

```
//If oldMap is null, then this is an insert
if(Trigger.oldMap == null || Trigger.oldMap.get(s.Id).Rep_1_Production_Site_Rep_v3__c != s.Rep_1_Production_Site_Rep_v3__c){
   //Perform your update on Customer_Number_from_ZipKey__c
}
```

Note: that while the trigger approach will work, this could be easily done via a workflow field update as well.

//Edit: According to your comment you want this to work only on update.  So either remove the before insert in line 1 of your trigger if you don't have any additional logic you are performing, or change the if check to the following:

```
if(Trigger.oldMap != null && Trigger.oldMap.get(s.Id).Rep_1_Production_Site_Rep_V3__c != s.Rep_1_Production_Site_Rep_v3__c)
```

For an idea of when each of the variables are available in a trigger, please see the following document: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm

Comment: Can you update my code with yours? I don't want to update Customer number if it is insert, and it appears that the If you wrote will actually update it.  Am I not understanding it?